# Rails g scaffold User email not working.Os Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I am kind if stuck here. 
      invoke  active_record
/home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration': Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in`block (2 levels) in '
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`execute_hook'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in`'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:179:in`pluralize_table_names?'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:119:in `table_name'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb:21:in`create_migration_file'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`each'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`invoke_all'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in`invoke'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in`with_padding'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in`_invoke_from_option_orm'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`each'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`invoke_all'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in`'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in`generate_or_destroy'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    from /home/frank/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in`require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended using RVM rather RBenv when it comes to Linux OS, and it's pretty easy to install. Here's what you would need to do to:

Make sure you install curl

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then visit the homepage of RVM at https://rvm.io/

add the key by copying and pasting this:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

then inside rails 4 with the following command:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

after install is done do this:

```
/home/<whatever your username is>/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
```

check to make sure you have ruby, ruby gem, and rails installed with the following command:

```
ruby -v && gem -v && rails -v
```

You should now by able to make simple rails app with the following command:

```
rails new testapp
```

Comment: i use rbenv on my server if do this i have to do it everything again any other solution

Comment: What was the command you used when you tried to generate scaffold? Was it the following:  "rails g scaffold user email:string". Also did you remember to run rake db:migrate.

Comment: i have solved it no issue now thanks all i had to do is to rebuild the project again.

Answer (score 1):

Error is saying that you don't have `database.yml` file

```
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
```

Please check your `config` directory. Can you see `database.yml` file in there?